# Dynamically view and hide Spinners in an Activity

Tags: android, json, android-spinner

I want to generate Spinners dynamically. Maximum numbers of Spinners I want to generate is 7. But I want to generate Spinners according to the data sets I'm getting from json response.

For the moment I have below shown code, which is used to identify how many spinners to generate. According to the below code `MealDealCatCode` contains L1, L2. So I want to get the value as 2 and display only 2 Spinners out of 7 (Hide remaining 5 Spinners).

How is possible to achieve my task. Any help will be appreciated.

```
@Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(JSONArray responseJson) {

        try {
            List<String> MainMenuDescription1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> MainMenuDescription2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> MainMenuDescription3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> MainMenuDescription4 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> MainMenuDescription5 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> MainMenuDescription6 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> MainMenuDescription7 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> MealDealCatCode = new ArrayList<String>();
            int uniqueItemIdCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < responseJson.length(); ++i) {
                JSONObject object = responseJson.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray subMenuArray = object
                        .getJSONArray("MealDealItemEntity");

                for (int j = 0; j < subMenuArray.length(); ++j) {
                    JSONObject subMenuObject = subMenuArray.getJSONObject(j);

                    Log.i("MealDealCatCode ",
                            subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode"));
                    MealDealCatCode.add(subMenuObject
                            .getString("MealDealCatCode"));
                    MealDealCatCode = Utils
                            .removeDuplicatesFromList(MealDealCatCode);

                    uniqueItemIdCount = MealDealCatCode.size();

                    if (subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode").trim()
                            .equals("L1")) {
                        Log.i("MainMenuDescription",
                                subMenuObject.getString("MainMenuDescription"));
                        MainMenuDescription1.add(subMenuObject
                                .getString("MainMenuDescription"));

                    }
                    if (subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode").trim()
                            .equals("L2")) {

                        MainMenuDescription2.add(subMenuObject
                                .getString("MainMenuDescription"));

                    }
                    if (subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode").trim()
                            .equals("L3")) {

                        MainMenuDescription3.add(subMenuObject
                                .getString("MainMenuDescription"));

                    }
                    if (subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode").trim()
                            .equals("L4")) {

                        MainMenuDescription4.add(subMenuObject
                                .getString("MainMenuDescription"));

                    }
                    if (subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode").trim()
                            .equals("L5")) {

                        MainMenuDescription5.add(subMenuObject
                                .getString("MainMenuDescription"));

                    }
                    if (subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode").trim()
                            .equals("L6")) {

                        MainMenuDescription6.add(subMenuObject
                                .getString("MainMenuDescription"));

                    }
                    if (subMenuObject.getString("MealDealCatCode").trim()
                            .equals("L7")) {

                        MainMenuDescription7.add(subMenuObject
                                .getString("MainMenuDescription"));
                    }
                }

                item1SP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_item1);
                item2SP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_item2);
                item3SP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_item3);
                item4SP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_item4);
                item5SP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_item5);
                item6SP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_item6);
                item7SP = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp_item7);

                item1SP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                item2SP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                item3SP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                item4SP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                item5SP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                item6SP.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                item7SP.setVisibility(View.GONE);




                item1SP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
                MainMenuDescription1 = Utils
                        .removeDuplicatesFromList(MainMenuDescription1);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterOne = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        MainMenuDescription1);
                dataAdapterOne
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                item1SP.setAdapter(dataAdapterOne);
                item1SP.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        dataAdapterOne,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected, this));

                item2SP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
                MainMenuDescription2 = Utils
                        .removeDuplicatesFromList(MainMenuDescription2);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterTwo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        MainMenuDescription2);
                dataAdapterTwo
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                item2SP.setAdapter(dataAdapterTwo);
                item2SP.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        dataAdapterTwo,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected, this));

                item3SP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
                MainMenuDescription3 = Utils
                        .removeDuplicatesFromList(MainMenuDescription3);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterThree = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        MainMenuDescription3);
                dataAdapterThree
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                item3SP.setAdapter(dataAdapterThree);
                item3SP.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        dataAdapterThree,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected, this));

                item4SP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
                MainMenuDescription4 = Utils
                        .removeDuplicatesFromList(MainMenuDescription4);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterFour = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        MainMenuDescription4);
                dataAdapterFour
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                item4SP.setAdapter(dataAdapterFour);
                item4SP.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        dataAdapterFour,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected, this));

                item5SP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
                MainMenuDescription5 = Utils
                        .removeDuplicatesFromList(MainMenuDescription5);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterFive = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        MainMenuDescription5);
                dataAdapterFive
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                item5SP.setAdapter(dataAdapterFive);
                item5SP.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        dataAdapterFive,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected, this));

                item6SP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
                MainMenuDescription6 = Utils
                        .removeDuplicatesFromList(MainMenuDescription6);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterSix = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        MainMenuDescription6);
                dataAdapterSix
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                item6SP.setAdapter(dataAdapterSix);
                item6SP.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        dataAdapterSix,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected, this));

                item7SP.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());
                MainMenuDescription7 = Utils
                        .removeDuplicatesFromList(MainMenuDescription7);
                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapterSeven = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        MainMenuDescription7);
                dataAdapterSeven
                        .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                item7SP.setAdapter(dataAdapterSeven);
                item7SP.setAdapter(new NothingSelectedSpinnerAdapter(
                        dataAdapterSeven,
                        R.layout.contact_spinner_row_nothing_selected, this));
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: As the maximum Number is fixed (7), you can create all spinners in your layout and set the visilbility gon. Whenever you need to show the spinner set the visibilitiy to VIsible

Comment: if you get both L1 and L2 does that mean , you will show the first and second spinner?

Comment: @StinePike I have uplaoded my complete code. Do you mind helping to display the spinners according to the number of uniqueItemIdCount. Now it hides all the spinners. Now I want to display number of items needed

Comment: @StinePike yes.. Now I'm getting the value for uniqueItemIdCount as 2. So I want to display only the 1st and 2nd spinners

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve what I want by following answer,

```
                for (int a = 0; a < uniqueItemIdCount; a++) {
                    if (uniqueItemIdCount == 1) {
                        item1SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (uniqueItemIdCount == 2) {
                        item1SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item2SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (uniqueItemIdCount == 3) {
                        item1SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item2SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item3SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (uniqueItemIdCount == 4) {
                        item1SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item2SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item3SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item4SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (uniqueItemIdCount == 5) {
                        item1SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item2SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item3SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item4SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item5SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (uniqueItemIdCount == 6) {
                        item1SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item2SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item3SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item4SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item5SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item6SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    if (uniqueItemIdCount == 7) {
                        item1SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item2SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item3SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item4SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item5SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item6SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        item7SP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                }
```